# How to refactor code with new operator

Tags: .net, oop, refactoring, new-operator, factory

here is a simple method which returns an anonymous object bases on some condition. I don't like the if condition in the code. is there a way to elegantly refactor the code ?

```
    public Object Get( TypeEnum typeName)
    {
        if( typeName == TypeEnum.A )
        {
            var factory = Factory.GetInstance<IContract<IA>>( );
            return new { A = factory.Object };
        }
        var factory = Factory.GetInstance<IContract<IB>>( );
        return new { B = factory.Object };
    }
```

edit: updated the condition now.

Comment: It depends what `someCondition` actually is. You should give some more context.

Comment: @hansmaad i have updated the question with more context. thanks.